# Android file copy prob in Android 10

Tags: android, filesystems, scoped-storage

I want to copy a image file to the scoped storage location. The image file is selected by user through any gallery app. The app is targeted to 29 and I am facing problem when I am running the code in device of API 29. Here is my code:

```
var photoSelectLauncher =
        registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
                    val proj = arrayOf(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)
                    val cursor =
                        requireContext().contentResolver.query(imgUri, proj, null, null, null)
                    cursor?.let {
                        val columnIndex = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA)
                        it.moveToFirst()
                        var issueImgPath = cursor.getString(columnIndex)
                        val selectedPhotoFile = File(issueImgPath)

                        if (selectedPhotoFile.length() / 1024 < 500) {

                            val timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis()

                val mediaStorageDir = File(activity.getExternalFilesDir("Android/data/com.app.project/files/Pictures"),"Images")

                if (!mediaStorageDir.exists() && !mediaStorageDir.mkdirs()) {
                    Log.d("File", "failed to create directory")
                }

                photoFile = File(mediaStorageDir.path + File.separator + "issue_photo_original_${timestamp}.jpg")

                            File(issueImgPath).copyTo(photoFile!!, true) // this line is giving problem
                           
                        }
                }
            }
```

Here is logcat:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Download/download.jpeg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
        at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:496)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:159)
        at kotlin.io.FilesKt__UtilsKt.copyTo(Utils.kt:235)
        at kotlin.io.FilesKt__UtilsKt.copyTo$default(Utils.kt:217)
        at com.beltmann.installation.ui.issues.LogIssueFragment$photoSelectLauncher$1.onActivityResult(LogIssueFragment.kt:838)
        at com.beltmann.installation.ui.issues.LogIssueFragment$photoSelectLauncher$1.onActivityResult(LogIssueFragment.kt:57)
        at androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultRegistry$1.onStateChanged(ActivityResultRegistry.java:145)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry$ObserverWithState.dispatchEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:354)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.forwardPass(LifecycleRegistry.java:265)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.sync(LifecycleRegistry.java:307)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.moveToState(LifecycleRegistry.java:148)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LifecycleRegistry.handleLifecycleEvent(LifecycleRegistry.java:134)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:3013)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start(FragmentStateManager.java:586)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:300)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1636)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:3063)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performStart(Fragment.java:3017)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.start(FragmentStateManager.java:586)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:300)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStore.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStore.java:112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1636)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:3112)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStart(FragmentManager.java:3063)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchStart(FragmentController.java:262)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:482)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:210)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1425)
        at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7825)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3294)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930) 
     Caused by: android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

Please help me to solve this problem.

Comment: it's all because `getPhotoFileUri` ...  99% `getPhotoFileUri` which are here on SO are fup(because the only right is to copy stream to app local file and provide path to it or not to use path at all but stream directly)

Comment: Sorry, it is just type-O. I have changed the same.

Comment: hehe you remove `getPhotoFileUri` from the question ... seriously then from where `photoFile` came?

Comment: `al mediaStorageDir = File(activity.getExternalFilesDir("Android/data/com.app.project/files/Pictures"),"Images")` better change that to: `val mediaStorageDir = File(activity.getExternalFilesDir("Pictures"),"Images")
`
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The image file is selected by user through any gallery app.

Then you will get a nice uri in onActivityResult. Use that uri.

Dont try to find a file path. You can open an input stream for the uri directly with

```
InputStream is = getContentResolver().openInoutStream(uri).
```

Then use that stream as if it was the file input stream you used before (well not really).

So write a copy finction that takes an uri as source.

Comment: any reason why you have this listed twice as an answer ?

Comment: Like Selvin already said: something goes wrong.